# How do I parse and format date data?

Tags: ruby, date, twitter

I wrote code to display tweets from a public account on Twitter:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'oauth'
require 'json'

# Now you will fetch /1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json,
# returns a list of public Tweets from the specified
# account.
baseurl = "https://api.twitter.com"
path    = "/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"
query   = URI.encode_www_form(
    "screen_name" => "CVecchioFX",
    "count" => 10,
)
address = URI("#{baseurl}#{path}?#{query}")
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new address.request_uri

# Print data about a list of Tweets
def print_timeline(tweets)
  # ADD CODE TO ITERATE THROUGH EACH TWEET AND PRINT ITS TEXT
  tweets.each do |tweet|
    puts "#{tweet["user"]["name"]} , #{tweet["text"]} , #{tweet["created_at"]} , #    {tweet["id"]}"
  end
end

# Set up HTTP.
http             = Net::HTTP.new address.host, address.port
http.use_ssl     = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER

# If you entered your credentials in the first
# exercise, no need to enter them again here. The
# ||= operator will only assign these values if
# they are not already set.
consumer_key = OAuth::Consumer.new(
    )
access_token = OAuth::Token.new(
    )

# Issue the request.
request.oauth! http, consumer_key, access_token
http.start
response = http.request request

# Parse and print the Tweet if the response code was 200
tweets = nil
if response.code == '200' then
  tweets = JSON.parse(response.body)
  print_timeline(tweets)
end
nil
```

The date is coming out as "Tue Jun 11 15:35:31 +0000 2013". What do I do to parse through the date and change it to a format such as "06.11.2013"?

Comment: You could have written a small code to illustrate your problem...you ok with these keys being public

Comment: OK or not, they're now a matter of public record since nothing ever goes away on Stack Overflow, not even edited data. The OP will have to get new keys issued.

Answer (score 2):

Use Ruby's standard library Date:

```
require 'date'

d = DateTime.parse('Tue Jun 11 15:35:31 +0000 2013')
puts d.strftime('%m.%d.%y')
```

In your code, just update print_timeline method:

```
def print_timeline(tweets)
  tweets.each do |tweet|
    d = DateTime.new(tweet['created_at'])
    puts "#{tweet['user']['name']} , #{tweet['text']} , #{d.strftime('%m.%d.%y')} , #{tweet['id']}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Where would this code be entered to change the displayed date?

Comment: Inside of print_timeline loop. Parse the data from tweet['created_at'] and puts the formatted data.

Comment: So that loop would look like this:

# Print data about a list of Tweets
def print_timeline(tweets)
  # ADD CODE TO ITERATE THROUGH EACH TWEET AND PRINT ITS TEXT
  tweets.each do |tweet|
    puts "#{tweet["user"]["name"]} , #{tweet["text"]} , #{tweet["created_at"]} , #{tweet["id"]}"
    d = DateTime.parse('#{tweet["created_at"]')
puts d.strftime('%m.%d.%y')
  end
end

Comment: I am still running into the error 'uninitialized constant Context::DateTime'

Comment: on the top of your file, you should insert: require 'date'. @ConnorMartinuzzi